# conflicting css files while including it in .jsp ppage

Tags: css, jsp, include, conflict

Whenever I am trying to include an .html page (which contain a navigation bar in bootstrap code) in my jsp page, then it doesn't show all the details on navigation bar. But whenever I tried to include it in a separate single page, it shows everything. It is clear that there might be a conflicting .css file, because I have some code in my jsp file.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to examine the css in question myself (which might help matters) all I can really do is advise how to examine CSS.

Using Google Chrome, the best way to figure out CSS conflicts is to right click on an element - e.g. the problematic nav bar - and click <kbd>Inspect Element</kbd>.

This should bring up a bar similar to the one shown here:
[image: screenshot of this post in the chrome inspect element tab]

Note the styling details on the left - it allows you to easily trace where the CSS that affects the element you've inspected comes from. More importantly, it also has a line through 'padding:.6em .8em;' - this is an overridden style, and the padding a bit further below which has no underlines is the style that overrides it.

If you're having CSS problems like this, you should be able to trace which styles are being overridden using the chrome inspect window. If you post your CSS, I might be able to be a bit more specific.